# cts:search and search:search while dealing with json docs

Tags: search, marklogic

My json doc looks like this:

```
{
  "directions": ["Heat oil in heavy... "], 
  "rating": 5, 
  "title": "Mahi-Mahi in Tomato Olive Sauce", 
  "ingredients": [
    "2 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil", 
    "1 cup chopped onion", 
    "1 cup dry white wine", 
    "1 teaspoon anchovy paste", 
  ], 
  "sodium": null
}
```

When I run:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),"anchovy")/title/string()
```

I get: `Mahi-Mahi in Tomato Olive Sauce`, which is desired.

But when I run:

```
search:search("anchovy", $options)/search:result/title/string()
```

I get an empty sequence. Note: I have set transform-results = "raw".

P.S I observed that `search:search("anchovy", $options)/search:result` gives a doc that appears to be in text format rather than json.

Is it possible to obtain the desired results using `search:search` in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"><transform-results apply="raw" /><extract-metadata>
        <json-property>title</json-property>
    </extract-metadata></options>;

search:search("anchovy", $options)//title/text()
```

Here we are specifying a JSON property to be extracted from the document and placed into the resultset.

As a side note, you may want to look at using [ServerSide JavaScript](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/getting-started/javascript) if you're working a lot with JSON documents, and in that case you could also utilise [jsearch](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript).